# Hbase regionservers

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have installed hadoop cluster. We want to use HBase over it. My hbase-site.xml is below

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://ali:54310/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>ali,reg_server1</value>
    <description>The directory shared by region servers.
    </description>
  </property>


  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
    </description>
  </property>
```

And I have 2 region servers ali and reg_server1. When I open page at http://ali:60010 I see that server reg_server1 has 0 regions. but server ali has n > 0 regions. I put some data to Hbase but, server reg_server1 still has 0 regions. Does it means that this node is not participiating in cluster? How can I resolve it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you are ok as long as you see both regionservers in the master's web UI.  When you write to an HBase table, it will write to one region (one region is always on one regionserver, in your case, ali).  Once you write enough data to make the region exceed the [configured max file size](http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.20.6/hbase-conf.html), the region will be split and distributed across the two regionservers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I one of servers become unavailable it is still shown on Web UI. Is it correct?

Comment: That's correct.  This probably was not clear- what I meant was that if the regionserver is shown on the master's web ui *when everything is working normally*, then eventually the data will be split across multiple regionservers.